# When submitting form, include data from an element on the page not in that form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Google searches warned not to nest forms. It's a nono to make big outer form holding some extra data to include in bunch of small inner forms. Fair enough. But then can someone help me solve this problem:

I have:

```
    <form method="get">
      Square
      <br>Row: <input name="row">
      <br>Col: <input name="col">

      <input type="hidden" name="place_island" value="square">
      <input type="submit" style="display: none">
    </form>
```

(And a bunch of other small form groups like that, for other shapes)

At the top of the page I also have something like this:

```
  <form id="player_select">
    <input type="radio" name="which_player" value="player1" checked="checked">Player1
    <br><input type="radio" name="which_player" value="player2">Player2
  </form>
```

When I submit one of the shape forms, I need to include which of those radio buttons is checked.

So for example, as-is, when I submit a shape form, I might get:
`Parameters: %{"col" => "asdasd", "place_island" => "square", "row" => "12345"}`

But I need it to also include:
`"which_player" => "player2"`

I'd rather avoid javascript unless it's fairly simple. Is there a way to do this in vanilla html? (And if not, can you tell me the javascript solution? <3 )

Comment: How are you submitting your form? Is it ajax or otherwise. Also the only html solution to this is include the radio button within the form, else javascript is the only possible option.

Comment: If you leave action blank it submits to this same page. I could have written `<form action="#">`. I have like 15 of the shape forms. I can't repeat the "which player is looking at this page" selector 15 times, it wouldn't make sense in the context

Comment: Can you show me what the javascript solution is if possible? <3

Comment: @Bukov i know if you leave action blank it submits to same page. But when you use ajax to submit a form you have more control over what is posted . You can modify the data easily etc. So is ajax OK with you?

Comment: Yes AJAX is fine if that's a different solution then Jaromanda's rude answer about "just write javascript you failure" even tho the original question was asking to do it in vanilla html. Currently I submit just by pressing enter with that `<input type="submit" style="display: none">`. What would your AJAX solution use sir?

Comment: You still will be able to use submit button to submit not a problem. Let me post a solution for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future readers, here's the solution. Disappointed it required js and there wasn't a regular html way to do it, but oh well

```
<form
  id="square_form"
  method="get"
  onsubmit="check_player_radio('square_form')"
>
```

and

```
 <script>
   function check_player_radio(form_id) {
     const which_player = document.querySelector('input[name = "which_player"]:checked').value

     $('#' + form_id).append('<input type="hidden" name="which_player" value="' + which_player +'">')
   }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet where you get the form values and create a FormData object with it and the add or remove key value pairs from it. If you observer the first line of code in the function `getFormData` that is `event.preventDefault();` this actually stops the form from being submitted and makes it available to you to handle as per the need.

```js
function getFormData(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var form = document.querySelector('form');
  var data = new FormData(form);
  data.append('player', document.getElementById('player').value);
  console.log(data.get('player'));
  console.log(data.get('FirstName'));
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="getFormData(event)">
  First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey"><br> Last name: <input type="text" name="LastName" value="Mouse"><br>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<input type="radio" id="player" value="player1">
```

Once you have all you form data available and the custom value added to it you can post is to the server using `XMLHttpRequest`. [Read more about XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)
Below is the piece of code that will post it to the server
  // below is the code you can use it to post to the server

```
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", '/server', true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { // Call a function when the state changes.
  if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200) {
      // Request finished. Do processing here.
    }
  }
  xhr.send(data);
```

The above solution is vanilla javascript. If you want and are ok can even use other ajax libraries jQuery being the most widely used.

[Jquery Ajax Docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

[More about FormData here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

This should solve your problem.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Cool and helpful, ty sir! xD

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>

    </style>
    </head>
<body>


    <form id="numberForm">
        <input type="radio" name="which_player" value="player1" checked="checked">Player1
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="which_player" value="player2">Player2

    </form>


    <form method="get">
            Square
            <br>Row: <input name="row">
            <br>Col: <input name="col">

            <input type="hidden" id="get_wich_player" name="get_wich_player" value="">

            <input type="hidden" name="place_island" value="square">
            <input id="btn" type="submit" style="display: show">
          </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
            var formInput = document.getElementById("numberForm");
            document.getElementById('get_wich_player').value=formInput.which_player.value;
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. There's like 15 of those shape forms with `<input type="submit" style="display: none">`. Do I need 3 lines of javascript for ever one of them?

Comment: this won't work because the default action of submitting a form will result in no actual code being executed